# Division equation in latex

Tags: latex

I googled, but the only examples i found with frac was with numbers or simple variables, no one near with alpha, beta or pi.

Can somebody please help me with this equation? Or provide an example using frac with alpha, beta and pi?

Here is my equation that gives me error.

```
\textit{$\gamma_{i}$(t)$\equiv$ P($X_{t}$ = i $\vert$ Y,$\theta$)} = \frac{$\alpha_{i}$ (t) $\beta_{i}$ (t)} {$\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N}$ $\alpha_{j}$ (t) $\beta_{j}$(t)}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need the italics, or the many sets of dollar signs. Try something more like this:

```
$\gamma_{i}(t)\equiv P(X_{t} = i \vert Y,\theta) = \frac{\alpha_{i} (t) \beta_{i} (t)} {\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N} \alpha_{j} (t) \beta_{j}(t)}$
```

Gives (tested with [this online LaTeX editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot, and thanks for the online LateX editor it is very helpful. :)